# NullReferenceException was unhandledby user code

Tags: vb.net

I am making a registration page and while using an input tag to upload image of the user, it is giving an error while running the website: "NullReferenceException was unhandledby user code". Please help me to sort this out. The method which is giving error is:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var path = "Memberimg";
    string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Memberimg") + "\\" + fn;
    if ((f1.PostedFile != null) && (f1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
    {

        try
        {
            f1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);

            Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);

        }

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Please select a file to upload.");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to f1.PostedFile before checking to see if it is null, in the line with:

```
string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f1.PostedFile.FileName);
```